# How to split text string to parts?

Tags: javascript, string, split

I have the following string:

```
var str = '01. Part1. 02. Part2. 04. Part3';
```

From which I need to get array of:

```
['01. Part1.', '02. Part2.', '04. Part3']
```

So far I have tried:

```
str.split(/\d+.(.*)/);
```

But the result is not I need:

```
["", " Part1. 02. Part2. 04. Part3", ""]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue is that `*` is greedy. Make it lazy by adding `?`. Also, this works better with the [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)method, as `split` will treat the regular expression matches as delimiters, which (without capture group) will not be included in the result.

```js
var str = '01. Part1. 02. Part2. 04. Part3';

var arr = str.match(/\d+\..*?(\.|$)/g);

console.log(arr);
```

The `(\.|$)` part is there to tell up to where `.*?` should go, and deal with the difference at the end of the string, where there is no terminal dot, like for the other parts. `$` matches with *end-of-string*.

Answer (score 1):

One approach:

```js
var str = '01. Part1. 02. Part2. 04. Part3';
console.log(
  // here we split the string on word-boundaries ("\b")
  // followed by a number ("(?=\d)")
  str.split(/\b(?=\d)/)
  // here we iterate over the Array returned by
  // String.prototype.split()
  .map(
    // using an Arrow function, in which
    // 'match' is a reference to the current
    // Array-element of the array over which
    // we're iterating.
    // here we return a new Array composed of
    // each Array-element, with the leading and
    // trailing white-spaces, using
    // String.prototype.trim():
    match => match.trim()
  )
); // ["01. Part1.", "02. Part2.", "04. Part3"]
```

References:

- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).
- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) (MDN).
- [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

Answer (score 0):

One more approach, by using negative lookahead:

```js
var str = '01. Part1. 02. Part2. 04. Part3';

arr=str.split(/\s(?![a-zA-Z])/g); //match space not followed by letters

console.log(arr);
```